# Doing something before map task starting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I'm currently using hadoop to process a counting task for a large dataset(around 3 gigs).I need to count something which fills in the same time slot.For example: counting the number of records which have time tags between 3am and 4am. I need the output to be continuous.If there is no record in certain time slot, I still want to keep it in the output,like [3am~4am, 0 records].

To accomplish this,I came up with an idea that I can put all the time slots with values of 0 into the mapping output before map task starts. But I tried google and I couldn't find solutions.

So is there any way I can output something before the map task starts? I will also appreciate for any new ideas to achieve the aim.
Thanks

Comment: add some sample input data you have and output you want?

Comment: for input like:   {[10am,1],[2pm,2]}, and for output i want somethings like{[10am,1],[11am,0],[12am,0],[1pm,0],[2pm,2]...}

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do it in the same time with your counting task, to save time.

Let's suppose you have the following file/table

> date  time     product     value
>  
>   2016,   14:00,  Samsung,    100
>   2016,   15:30,  LG,         130
>   2016,   15:59,  Nexus,      50
>   2016,   18:10,  LG,         15

and you want to group by product and find out the total for each product,  but in the same time you want to count the number of records which have time tags between 3am and 4am

Just define your custom key in you mapper class and send it to context, depends of your condition

```
public class Mapper_WordsCount extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        String line = value.toString();
        String[] items = line.split(",")


        //define a custom key
        String myCustomKey = "3am-4am";

        //put 0 by default. Only if you want to have result like: [3am-4am, 0 records]
        context.write(new Text(myCustomKey),IntWritable(0));

        // check you condition
        if ( isBetween_3am_and_4am( items[1] ) ) {    //  write your function 
            //count the record like you want
            context.write(new Text(myCustomKey),one);
        }

        ......
        your java code
        ......

    }
}
```

Comment: check the input/output I just posted, I don't think your solution works for me